# stage error in fuerte

Tags: simulation, ros-fuerte, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just installed Fuerte and tried a simulation with stage. But, when I tried to apply tutorials given in ROS, it gives the error related to model type of the laser:

**err: Model type laser not found in model typetable (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)**

**err: Unknown model type laser in world file. (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)**

any idea how to solve these problems? Thanks in advance...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33973/stage-error-in-fuerte/) by [musti](https://answers.ros.org/users/2364/musti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just encountered the same.

Apparently, you just need to replace all occurrences of "laser" with "ranger" (as per [this post](http://blog.aus10.org/?p=125) )

Here's a handy one-liner to do so (for all stage files below current directory):

```
`perl -p -i -e 's/laser/ranger/g' $(find . -name *.world) $(find . -name *.inc)`
```

I also notice the `upgrade-world.sh` script in stage pkg... may be useful for getting rid of other deprecated stuff in your .world files?

UPDATE: looks like you also have to wrap your laser in a "sensor" block...

So the old sick.inc ...

```
define sick laser
(
    range_max 80
    fov 180.0
    samples 180
    size [ 0.156 0.155 0.19 ]
)
```

Has now become:

```
define sick ranger
(
  sensor(
    range [ 0 80 ]
    fov 180.0
    samples 180
  )
  size [ 0.156 0.155 0.19 ]
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2012-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-27**:
@Nick Armstrong-Crews Hi, I wrote two of the stage tutorials available at ROS (stage 3.2.2, which works on diamondback and electric) - does this modification work with the roomba-wander.world at http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers ?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-28**:
Thanks for the detailed example, Nick. We should add a migration link to the Stage wiki page.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-28**:
@joq Yep ! that is exactly what I was thinking about !

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-28**:
@Nick Armstrong-Crews Hi, I could not make roomba-wander.world to work with that change in fuerte ! :-( ! Anyway, I am just staring off with fuerte !

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2014-09-18**:
Hi , I made the changes but now it says :
warn: worldfile roomba_lse_arena.world:32 : property [color] is defined but not used (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/worldfile.cc WarnUnused)

**Comment by [Sanjay Nag](https://answers.ros.org/users/44551/sanjay-nag/) on 2019-08-15**:
This didn't work for me!
Did anyone got this working on Stage_ROS kinetic? Facing the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte has stage 4.1.1 (Electric had 3.2.2).

Stage version 4 no longer supports the `laser` model, it has been replaced by a more generic `ranger` interface.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several issues when using Fuerte and Stage 4.1.1 regarding stage controllers.

Re:   `warn: Model roomba.ranger:1 not found`

The stageros wrapper only expects one ranger per robot but the wander controller
in Stage expects the laser to be the second ranger. The line in `wander.cc` that causes this warning is:

```
robot->laser = (ModelRanger*)mod->GetChild( "ranger:1" );
```

Re:    `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

This appears to be related to the use of the roomba model (when I inspected the stack trace the problem was in some drawing code) - pioneer or simple position models work OK (once `wander.cc` has been edited).

However, stageros will stop all robots that have not received a velocity command in the last 0.2 seconds which is a problem if using a stage controller to control that robot.

To address these issues, I forked the Stage repository and edited `stage.hh` and `model.cc` to store and expose a `uses_controller` attribute for each `Model`. I then edited `stageros.cpp` (in a local copy of the stage stack) to make use of it, so that robots that have stage controllers are not exposed to ROS. I also edited `wander.cc` to get the first ranger it finds for any robot (this will break the simple.world demo found in Stage/worlds - I've added a gsh-simple.world demo that will work)

My forked repo is available at git://github.com/grahamhorn/Stage.git

I've included my edited `stageros.cpp` file in a `stageros` directory.

These commands should get things working:

First create an overlay for stage in your `$ROS_WORKSPACE`

```
$ roslocate info turtlebot | rosws merge -
$ rosws update
```

and build it:

```
$ rosmake stage
```

Then clone my Stage repo and build it:

```
$ mkdir stage4
$ cd stage4
$ git clone git://github.com/grahamhorn/Stage.git
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ROS_WORKSPACE/stage Stage
$ make install
```

Test:

In one terminal:

```
$ roscore
```

In a second terminal:

```
$ rosrun stage stageros <your path>/stage4/Stage/worlds/gsh-simple.world
```

You should see one moving robot (controlled by the wander controller) and one static robot (exposed to ROS and waiting for commands).

---

Originally posted by [Graham](https://answers.ros.org/users/3313/graham/) with karma: 86 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-04**:
@Graham what still surprises me is that the wrapper (and everything else, roomba model and also the stage controllers) worked nicely in Electric and Diamondback but in gave error in Fuerte.

**Comment by [Graham](https://answers.ros.org/users/3313/graham/) on 2012-10-09**:
I've only tried it in Fuerte. The switch to Stage version 4 is the main cause of the problems.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-09**:
@Graham Just a gut feel - I would expect that only tinkering with the stageros wrapper should solve the problem. One may not need to dig into wander.cc, wander.cc is a part of parent stage (https://github.com/rtv/Stage) and playing with that may not be greatly advisable.

**Comment by [Graham](https://answers.ros.org/users/3313/graham/) on 2012-10-16**:
I needed to edit Stage to expose information about whether models used a controller. I agree that rather than editing wander.cc I should have edited a copy e.g. wander-ranger-only.cc.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-11-19**:
@Graham Have been going through your repository - have you got the goal directed stage controller to work ? is the goal coordinates given as hard coded into the code script or through some graphical means (rviz etc) ?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-11-19**:
@Graham your code compiles and also builds - but could not make it run. Guess it may be better to communicate via email.

**Comment by [cldoppler](https://answers.ros.org/users/11411/cldoppler/) on 2014-01-29**:
@Graham: Hi, although this post is a bit older I would like to ask for some advice using your stage overlay. It did not work. I had to make a STAGEPATH variable containing Folders for libs and ctrl. Now Stage comes up, ctrl is initialized but robot does not move. Pose data (verbose) is weird. Ideas?

**Comment by [cldoppler](https://answers.ros.org/users/11411/cldoppler/) on 2014-01-29**:
@Graham: also both robots of your example are visible in rostopics despite one has der "wander_single_ranger" control.

**Comment by [cldoppler](https://answers.ros.org/users/11411/cldoppler/) on 2014-01-30**:
got it going - finally. Had to "make all" the stage stack after replacing original source files with your edited ones.

**Comment by [msturnage](https://answers.ros.org/users/6349/msturnage/) on 2014-02-21**:
Would you post the code and changes to be able to run wander controller for Stage 4.1.1 and fuerte

**Comment by [cldoppler](https://answers.ros.org/users/11411/cldoppler/) on 2014-02-24**:
I am not a big programmer nor did I add any vital code to Grahams Version. Just create your ROSWS, then get original stage into your WS and check that the overlay is working (rospack find stage should point to your overlay). Then follow Grahams instructions, replace orig. stage files with Grahams forked ones.

**Comment by [cldoppler](https://answers.ros.org/users/11411/cldoppler/) on 2014-02-24**:
Then MAKE both: stage4 form Graham and stage in your ROSWS. After that you should be able to start the Simulation.